# What does ParallelQuerys Count count?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, parallel-processing

*I'm testing a self written element generator (`ICollection<string>`) and compare the calculated count to the actual count to get an idea if there's an error or not in my algorithm.*

As this generator can generate lots of elements on demand I'm looking in `Partitioner<string>` and I have implemented a basic one which seems to also produce valid enumerators which together give the same amount of `string`s as calculated.

Now I want to test how this behaves if run parallel *(again first testing for correct count)*:

```
MyGenerator generator = new MyGenerator();
MyPartitioner partitioner = new MyPartitioner(generator);

int isCount = partitioner.AsParallel().Count();
int shouldCount = generator.Count;

bool same = isCount == shouldCount; // false
```

**I don't get why this count is not equal!** What is the `ParallelQuery<string>` doing?

```
generator.Count() == generator.Count // true

partitioner.GetPartitions(xyz).Select(enumerator =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }).Sum() == generator.Count // true
```

So, I'm currently not seeing an error in my code. Next I tried to manualy count that `ParallelQuery<string>`:

```
int count = 0;
partitioner.AsParallel().ForAll(e => Interlocked.Increment(ref count));
count == generator.Count // true
```

**Summed up:** Everyone counts my enumerable correct, `ParallelQuery.ForAll` enumerates exactly `generator.Count` elements. **But what does `ParallelQuery.Count()`?**

*If the correct count is something about 10k, ParallelQuery sees 40k.*

---

```
    internal sealed class PartialWordEnumerator : IEnumerator<string>
    {
        private object sync = new object();

        private readonly IEnumerable<char> characters;

        private readonly char[] limit;

        private char[] buffer;
        private IEnumerator<char>[] enumerators;

        private int position = 0;

        internal PartialWordEnumerator(IEnumerable<char> characters, char[] state, char[] limit)
        {
            this.characters = new List<char>(characters);

            this.buffer = (char[])state.Clone();

            if (limit != null)
            {
                this.limit = (char[])limit.Clone();
            }

            this.enumerators = new IEnumerator<char>[this.buffer.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < this.buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                this.enumerators[i] = SkipTo(state[i]);
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator<char> SkipTo(char c)
        {
            IEnumerator<char> first = this.characters.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator<char> second = this.characters.GetEnumerator();

            while (second.MoveNext())
            {
                if (second.Current == c)
                {
                    return first;
                }

                first.MoveNext();
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        private bool ReachedLimit
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.limit == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < this.buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (this.buffer[i] != this.limit[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }

        public string Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.buffer == null)
                {
                    throw new ObjectDisposedException(typeof(PartialWordEnumerator).FullName);
                }

                return new string(this.buffer);
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return this.Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            lock (this.sync)
            {
                if (this.position == this.buffer.Length)
                {
                    this.position--;
                }

                if (this.position == -1)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                IEnumerator<char> enumerator = this.enumerators[this.position];

                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    this.buffer[this.position] = enumerator.Current;
                    this.position++;

                    if (this.position == this.buffer.Length)
                    {
                        return !this.ReachedLimit;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return this.MoveNext();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.enumerators[this.position] = this.characters.GetEnumerator();
                    this.position--;

                    return this.MoveNext();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.position = -1;
            this.buffer = null;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public override IList<IEnumerator<string>> GetPartitions(int partitionCount)
    {
        IEnumerator<string>[] enumerators = new IEnumerator<string>[partitionCount];

        List<char> characters = new List<char>(this.generator.Characters);

        int length = this.generator.Length;

        int characterCount = this.generator.Characters.Count;

        int steps = Math.Min(characterCount, partitionCount);

        int skip = characterCount / steps;

        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            char c = characters[i * skip];

            char[] state = new string(c, length).ToCharArray();
            char[] limit = null;

            if ((i + 1) * skip < characterCount)
            {
                c = characters[(i + 1) * skip];
                limit = new string(c, length).ToCharArray();
            }

            if (i == steps - 1)
            {
                limit = null;
            }

            enumerators[i] = new PartialWordEnumerator(characters, state, limit);
        }

        for (int i = steps; i < partitionCount; i++)
        {
            enumerators[i] = Enumerable.Empty<string>().GetEnumerator();
        }

        return enumerators;
    }
```

Comment: It's much more unlikely there is a significant bug in `ParallelQuery.Count` method.  Why not include your `MyGenerator` and `MyPartitioner` source code in some way that the community can help you look into it?

Comment: @mellamokb That'd be tons of code, but as I showed: `ForAll` enumerates the correct amount, calling `GetPartitions` and then summing the count of elements produced by the enumerators also gives the correct count. _(`AsParallel` lazily calls `GetPartitions` for 4 partitions, so do I manually)_

Comment: How about a simple, self-contained example that demonstrates the issue, that can be run in say, LINQPad?  Just reduce it down to the bare necessities.  I have a feeling the issue is related to `ParallelQuery.Count` running multiple threads simultaneously with objects that are not thread-safe, but it's impossible to tell that without more information about what your code does.  Note that it may be possible that calling `Interlocked.Increment(ref count)` will force the parallel threads to synchronize with one another, whereas just a straight `ParallelQuery.Count` would not.

Comment: The enumerators returned by `GetPartitions` do not share objects, everyone has it's own (deep) copy of the essential information.

Comment: @mellamokb Uhm, are the same enumerators called on different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I believe I have found the solution.  According to the documentation on [`IEnumerable.MoveNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> If MoveNext passes the end of the collection, the enumerator is
>   positioned after the last element in the collection and MoveNext
>   returns false. When the enumerator is at this position, **subsequent
>   calls to MoveNext also return false until Reset is called**.

According to the following logic:

```
    private bool ReachedLimit
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.limit == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < this.buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.buffer[i] != this.limit[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

The call to `MoveNext()` will return false only one time - when the buffer is exactly equal to the limit.  Once you have passed the limit, the return value from `ReachedLimit` will start to become false again, making `return !this.ReachedLimit` return true, so the enumerator will continue past the end of the limit all the way until it runs out of characters to enumerate.  Apparently, in the implementation of `ParallelQuery.Count()`, `MoveNext()` is called multiple times when it has reached the end, and since it starts to return a true value again, the enumerator happily continues returning more elements (this is not the case in your custom code that walks the enumerator manually, and apparently also is not the case for the `ForAll` call, so they "accidentally" return the correct results).

The simplest fix to this is to remember the return value from `MoveNext()` once it becomes false:

```
private bool _canMoveNext = true;
public bool MoveNext()
{
    if (!_canMoveNext) return false;
    ...

        if (this.position == this.buffer.Length)
        {
            if (this.ReachedLimit) _canMoveNext = false;
    ...
}
```

Now once it begins returning false, it will return false for every future call and this returns the correct result from `AsParallel().Count()`.  Hope this helps!

---

The documentation on [Partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768.aspx) notes (emphasis mine):

> The static methods on Partitioner are all thread-safe and may
>   be used concurrently from multiple threads. However, while a created
>   partitioner is in use, the **underlying data source should not be
>   modified**, whether from the same thread that is using a partitioner or
>   from a separate thread.

From what I can understand of the code you have given, it would seem that `ParallelQuery.Count()` is most likely to have thread-safety issues because it may possibly be iterating multiple enumerators at the same time, whereas all the other solutions would require the enumerators to be run synchronized.  Without seeing the code you are using for `MyGenerator` and `MyPartitioner` is it difficult to determine if thread-safety issues could be the culprit.

---

To demonstrate, I have written a simple enumerator that returns the first hundred numbers as strings.  Also, I have a partitioner, that distributes the elements in the underlying enumerator over a collection of `numPartitions` separate lists.  Using all the methods you described above on our 12-core server (when I output `numPartitions`, it uses `12` by default on this machine), I get the expected result of 100 (this is LINQPad-ready code):

```
void Main()
{
    var partitioner = new SimplePartitioner(GetEnumerator());

    GetEnumerator().Count().Dump();

    partitioner.GetPartitions(10).Select(enumerator =>
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }).Sum().Dump();

    var theCount = 0;
    partitioner.AsParallel().ForAll(e => Interlocked.Increment(ref theCount));
    theCount.Dump();

    partitioner.AsParallel().Count().Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public IEnumerable<string> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        yield return i.ToString();
}

public class SimplePartitioner : Partitioner<string>
{
    private IEnumerable<string> input;
    public SimplePartitioner(IEnumerable<string> input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public override IList<IEnumerator<string>> GetPartitions(int numPartitions)
    {
        var list = new List<string>[numPartitions];
        for (var i = 0; i < numPartitions; i++)
            list[i] = new List<string>();
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var s in input)
            list[(index = (index + 1) % numPartitions)].Add(s);

        IList<IEnumerator<string>> result = new List<IEnumerator<string>>();
        foreach (var l in list)
            result.Add(l.GetEnumerator());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
100
100
100
100
```

This clearly works.  Without more information it is impossible to tell you what is not working in your particular implementation.

Comment: OK.. I still think the Partition code will be of interest as well.  I understand what the `PartialWordEnumerator` is doing, and I don't see any issues with it.  However, I'm not seeing how to paralellize it to see if I get the same results.

Comment: The `GetPartitions` code is a bit .. unfinished and not optimal, but its doing something like this for lets say characters 'A','B','C','D' and a string length of 4 (`AsParallel` demands 4 partitions): First partitioner from `'AAAA'` to `'BBBB'`, second from `'BBBB'` ...... and last from `'DDDD'` to `null`. As example: the first partitioner starts with a state of `"AAAA"` (but'll keep that after the first MoveNext as all enumerators are set to be before 'A', see `SkipTo`) and if it reaches "BBBB" it will check if this still belongs to him and in this case returns `false` so it's not included.

Comment: OK.  So I should technically just be able to write a stub partitioner that simply returns X `PartialWordEnumerator` instances, and send those to a `AsParallel().Count()` and see what behavior occurs.  It is interesting that you note the number returned is off by a factor of 4 (10k vs 40k), and you are using 4 partitions... is it *exactly* a factor of 4 for the count?  Seems like more than a coincidence...

Comment: Nah it's more 17k to 45k .. so not exactly. I'm going to post my `GetPartitions` code in a few moments.

Comment: OK.. I'm trying to run your code and it's crashing LINQPad (probably StackOverflow)...

Comment: NVM.  Discovered length was supposed to be length of character array, not length of overall enumeration.  It runs now.  I enumerating from `AAAA` to `DDDD` using all the letters from `A` to `Z`, and I get a total of about 450k.  Looks like it's going all the way to `ZZZZ` despite my limit. No matter, I will try parallelizing and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: OK Changed to run from `AAA` to `ZZZ`.  The `partitioner.GetPartitions(...).Select(...).Sum()` method returns `17576`.  But the `AsParallel().Count()` returns `118105` (on my 12-core machine)... interesting...

Comment: Indeed, 26^3 = 17576 last I checked.  Digging in deeper it looks like for some reason when running parallel in the debugger, they are all running to the final limit instead of their partitioned limits.  I tested with a real simple test case `A` to `Z`.  The parallel form returns `169`, but it should be `26`.  In fact, each partition is running say from `A` to `Z`, `C` to `Z`, `E` to `Z`, etc., which gives the total - 169, which is reproducible.  Don't know why yet...

Comment: See edit - I found the solution.  Your implementation of `MoveNext()` returns false only once, but it needs to return false continuously as long as the end of the enumeration has been reached.  Apparently, the way `AsParallel().Count()` is implemented, it makes multiple calls and so incorrectly assumes the enumeration hasn't finished and goes past the limit.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. Didn't expect that. This was the problem. The parallel version of `Count()` has an overhead with calling `MoveNext` multiple times even after a `false` and my bug broke everything. I changed my code to set the position to -1 after a `ReachedLimit == true`.